# How to position elements across an Axis (to fit perfectly)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given a row of elements (set of data points), each has a certain size & value (on the X axis), how can they be positioned across the same axis in such a way none will be overflowed?

*(The area which the circles are at is fluid in terms of width)*

#### Now:

[image]

#### Wanted:

[image]

### [Demo page](https://jsbin.com/coyitu/edit?html,css,js,output)

(A CSS-only solution will be preferred)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my [**demo**](https://jsbin.com/coyitu/edit?html,css,js,output) with this formula:

```
// A set of circles
var items = [
  { size:30, value:0 },
  { size:22, value:3 },
  { size:55, value:20 }, 
  { size:70, value:66 },
  { size:33, value:96 },
  { size:36, value:100 }
];


items.forEach(function(item, i){
  // create a "circle" element
  var elm = document.createElement('div');
  elm.className = 'circle';

  // set position & size
  elm.style.cssText = `padding   : ${item.size}px; 
                       left      : ${item.value}%; 
                       transform : translateX(-${item.value}%)`

  // add circle to document
  document.querySelector('section').appendChild(elm);
});
```

Using `translate` moves the element to the left, relative to it's value (which is the `left` position, so the more the element is to the right, the more it re-ajusts to the left, so the right-most element would re-adjust itself completely, meaning all it's width will be translated to the left, and the left-most element will not re-adjust itself at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to scale the entire circles distribution to fit in the available space (maintaining the ratio of X axis value). Try this:

```
body { 
    width:200px; /* Can be any witdth in % vw px etc */
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: how does that help in anything? the body doesn't need `position:relative`, that is the *default*. Also, it's already set to `100%` so I fail to understand what would your code do any further than the defaults already provides